# Abstract class > mandatory constructor for child classes

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I create an abstract constructor on an abstract C# class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504977/why-cant-i-create-an-abstract-constructor-on-an-abstract-c-sharp-class)

How can I write one abstract class that tells that is mandatory for the child class to have one constructor?

Something like this:

```
public abstract class FatherClass
{

    public **<ChildConstructor>**(string val1, string val2)
    {

    }

   // Someother code....
}

public class ChildClass1: FatherClass
{
    public ChildClass1(string val1, string val2)
    {
       // DO Something.....
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 1:

If I can't inherit constructors. How can I prevent that someone will NOT FORGET to implement that specific child class constructor ????

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot.

However, you could set a single constructor on the FatherClass like so:

```
protected FatherClass(string val1, string val2) {}
```

Which forces subclasses to call this constructor - this would 'encourage' them to provide a `string val1, string val2` constructor, but does not mandate it.

I think you should consider looking at the [abstract factory](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx) pattern instead. This would look like this:

```
interface IFooFactory {
    FatherClass Create(string val1, string val2);
}

class ChildClassFactory : IFooFactory
{
    public FatherClass Create(string val1, string val2) {
        return new ChildClass(val1, val2);
    }
}
```

Wherever you need to create an instance of a subclass of FatherClass, you use an IFooFactory rather than constructing directly. This enables you to mandate that `(string val1, string val2)` signature for creating them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that be default a non abstract / static class will always have a default empty public constructor unless you override it with private Constructor(){....}. I don't think you can force a constructor with 2 string params to be present in a child class.

Answer (score 0):

You do not inherit constructors. You would simply have to implement one yourself in every child class.

Answer (score 0):

You cant set a constructor as abstract, but you can do something like this:

```
 public abstract class Test
    {
        public Test(){}

        public Test(int id)
        {
            myFunc(id);
        }

        public abstract void myFunc(int id);
    }
```

Comment: **Never** call a virtual method in a class from its constructor! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506

Comment: dtb: Your link explains why not to invoke virtual methods on a Constructor, it's not quite the same as abstract methods. Never the less, I don't see why not if it is used a proper name and documentation.